# Catalyst: How to open settings on Mac?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, mac-catalyst

In the original IOS version of my app, the following code successfully opens settings:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString] options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success)
{
    ...
}];
```

But after building for Catalyst the command does nothing on the mac. The command does execute, the completion handler fires, and `success` is set to `TRUE`. But it does not open the settings window.

How do I programmatically open the settings on Mac Catalyst?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want to open *your* app’s settings or the macOS System Preferences?

The URL you’re using above opens the iOS Settings app To show your app’s settings, as specified in your Settings.bundle. On macOS, Catalyst apps will automatically create an in-app Preferences window for you from the Settings.bundle. Read more here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/mac_catalyst/displaying_a_preferences_window

If you want to open System Preferences, you may be able to do it via openURL using one of these URLs: https://www.mbsplugins.de/archive/2020-04-05/MacOS_System_Preference_Links

Comment: Good clarification, regarding the type of preferences. I am looking to open the account login page if they're not signed in to an apple ID. I guess per the second link, that's not openable programmatically?

Comment: That might be the iCloud pref pane you want, which that site says works. I think there are other (hacky) ways to open System Preferences, but i imagine they’ll all be tricky to do from a Catalyst app (I.e., they require Mac-specific APIs or permissions). OpenURL is your best bet, if you can find a URL that works.

Comment: I have tried to open System Preferences with Notifications and it works but it open Notification with selected first app on the list. Is there possibility to open it with my app selected so user don't has to scroll and look where it is? I can't find any solution on the internet